# Associativity of Join (Topology)

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I sincerely apologize if this is a very basic question. I'm new to Algebraic Topology and still trying to get a good grip on the subject. I started reading Hatcher's Algebraic Topology a couple of weeks ago and I was trying to solve the following problem:

**Exercise 0.18:**
Show that $S^m*S^n = S^{m+n+1}.$

**My Attempt:** Page 9 of the textbook says that $S^{n-1}$ is homeomorphic to the join of $n$ copies of $S^0.$ Using this, we can expand $S^{m+n+1}$ as $m+n+2$ copies of $S^0$ and collect the terms together to form $S^m$ and $S^n.$ However, in order to do this, the join needs to be associative and I am not sure how to prove the associativity of the join. Can someone please help me?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define $X*Y*Z$ as $\{(a,x,b,y,c,z) \in [0,1]\times X\times [0,1]\times Y\times [0,1]\times Z \vert a+b+c=1\}/\sim$

where $\sim$ is given by the relations:

$(0,x,b,y,c,z) \sim (0,x',b,y,c,z)$,

$(a,x,0,y,c,z)\sim (a,x,0,y',c,z)$,

$(a,x,b,y,0,z)\sim (a,x,b,y,0,z')$.

Now consider the map $$\phi : (X*Y)*Z \to X*Y*Z$$ defined as $$[([(x,b,y)],c,z)] \mapsto [((1-b)(1-c),x,(1-c)b,y,c,z)]$$.

Show that $\phi$ can be written as a composition of inclusion and projection maps, hence $\phi$ is continuous.

It is straightforward to check that $\phi$ is a bijection.

Now in your question, the domain is compact and codomain is Hausdorff so $\phi$ is a homeomorphism. Simillarly show that $X*(Y*Z)$ is homemorphic to $X*Y*Z$